# Android: Check session facebook do not work?

Tags: android, session, authentication

I use this code to check weather user logon facebook or not, if not it will open login page. I use the same code as example on facebook sdk(PlacePickerSample):

```
private boolean ensureOpenSession() {
    if (Session.getActiveSession() == null ||
            !Session.getActiveSession().isOpened()) {
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                onSessionStateChanged(session, state, exception);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But it doesn't work. It just go to black background then return to my app immediately. Dose anyone know why?

Thanks.

Comment: My fault: <activity
            android:name="com.example.cst_share.Share"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"> Remove android:launchMode and it should works...

Comment: call session.isOpened() to check if session is already opened.

Comment: I'm having this exact problem, and I don't see launchMode="singleInstance" in my manifest, so I'm guessing this isn't at fault for me. Can any one else shed some light on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, after printing out session information in lots of places I found I had the following exception being thrown:

```
Session: an attempt was made to reauthorize a session that has a pending request
```

The solution was to put the following method in the code that is calling ensureOpenSession:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: That's not exactly my problem. If you do not override onActivityResult() like that, Your app still open login page, but It cannot save your session. You still don't login after logined!!!! But But I mark your answer, someone may need it.